# issues setting static IP in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: networking, server, static-ip

I have my `/etc/network/interfaces` file setup as:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.140.98
    network 172.16.0.0
    broadcast 172.16.255.255
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 172.16.140.5
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Does any of that look wrong?
I deleted `dhcp-client` to prevent it from overwriting any of the static ip info. But now I can no longer connect to the Internet. :(

I've read many things, and tried different number combinations. Everywhere I look it tells me the same thing: Just edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and restart the interfaces! And tada - automagic! 
(I really like the sounds of automagic :) - to no avail for me though)

I find it odd, because I was able to set up a Raspberry Pi with static ip, just my editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. So I am really curious as to what is going wrong here, how do I diagnose? Where to begin. What do the numbers even mean?

I have no real understanding of how networking works. So that might be something to look into.

**output of ifconfig:**

```
eth0 
link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1d:60:b5:e3:52
inet addr:172.16.140.98 Bcast:172.16.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
inet6 addr: fe80::21d:60ff:feb5:e325/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:132893 errors:0 dropped:4705 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:11437695 (11.4MB) TX bytes:7862 (7.8KB)
lo
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:376 errors:0 dropped:4705 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:30244 (30.2KB) TX bytes:30224 (30.2 KB)
```

**output of ip route:**

```
default via 172.16.140.5 dev eth0
172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.140.98
```

**output of ip addr:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu65536 qdisc noqueue state UKNOWN group default
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever prefurred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preffered_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1d:60:b5:e3:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.16.140.98/16 brd 172.16.255.255 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::21d:60ff:feb5:e352/64 scope link
```

link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

**output of ping:**

```
ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

How do I start diagnostics to see where the issue lies???

Comment: Are the netmask in `/e/n/interfaces` really `255.255.0.0`? Remove `network` and `broadcast`, as they will be calculated by the computer from `address` and `netmask`. I would guess that the netmask should be `255.255.255.255.0`.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`? The problem with ping indicates of a problem with name resolution.  But you have to have a working network. So, what do `ping -c4 8.8.8.8` give? Try your router too, `ping -c4 172.16.140.5`.

Comment: thanks, it works now! 
feel a little silly for wasting your time over something so simple...

Comment: No problem. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably shorten it up a bit. As well, there appears to be no space between the DNS namesever addresses. I suggest:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.140.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.140.5
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8  8.8.4.4
```

Given the address of the gateway, I doubt you need to use 255.255.0.0.

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

And test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: network interface names has been changed in ubuntu 16.04 (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). Is this setting will workon ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: @seenu Please substitute your relevant interface for eth0 above. Find out with: `ifconfig -a` A PCI ethernet interface will most likely be something like *enp2s0* or some such. It should then work perfectly.